# jQuery is not defined Error and No method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

i m using [this autocomplete](http://yasserzaid.wordpress.com/2009/12/05/autocomplete-from-database-using-jquery/) function. I run it in new project and it really worked great. I moved it to my main project but it didnt work.
I looked to javascript console and i get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.autocomplete.js:2
(anonymous function)

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'
(anonymous function)
jQuery.fn.extend.ready jquery.js:2299
jQuery.extend.ready.jQuery.readyList jquery.js:2319
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:745
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:2318
```

I checked all paths.

```
 <script src="jscripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="skins/skin_1/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#Size").autocomplete("AutocompleteData.ashx");
     });
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#Color").autocomplete("AutoCompleteData2.ashx");
     });
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#Brand").autocomplete("AutoCompleteData3.ashx");
     });    
  </script>

<input type="text" ID="Size" runat="server"/>
<input type="text" ID="Color" runat="server"/>
<input type="text" ID="Brand" runat="server"/>
```

It works in normal aspx,html pages. But i have to put it in .config page.
It starts like this. I dont know how can i explain it.

```
<PackageTransform>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:asp="urn:asp" exclude-result-prefixes="asp">
```

Normally i have another jQuery and it works. Like this;

```
function moveScroller() {
            var a = function () {
            var b = $(window).scrollTop();
            var d = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top;
            var c = $("#scroller");
            if (b > d) {
            c.css({ position: "fixed", top: "0px" })
            } else {
            if (d >= b) {
            c.css({ position: "relative", top: "" })
            }
            }
            };
            $(window).scroll(a); a()
            }
```

How can i run it, or do you have any other autocomplete system which using database, keyboard arrows and mouse. Thank you, sorry for my english.

Comment: BTW, you dont need 3 `$(document).ready(...)` functions - 1 will do with all 3 of your calls to `autocomplete` in there.

Comment: Thank you i did it, and still not working

Comment: No, that wasnt to fix your problem - it was an observation (hence why I didnt put it as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the jscripts/jquery.js file .You said you have moved your project so may be that file is not completely uploaded and also check for jscripts/jquery.autocomplete.js
compare their size and check are they completele uploaded ?